# Why doesn't ssis fail when file header is incorrect?

Tags: ssis

SSIS always used to give me an error when the header row of a file did not match what was defined in the connection manager. It would typically state something about 'an error was encountered while skipping data rows'. I've recently had a couple of instances where it still loads data (most times incorrectly) and does not fail.

*Instance #1* - The column names did not match and it was even split into two rows, but all of the data loaded without error.

**Expected Header**
PA_ID|ClientID|DateOfRequest|Outcome|ServiceType|DiagnosisCD|ProcedureCD

**Actual Header**
"PA ID
Use LL auth number"|Client ID|Date of Request |Outcome|Service Type|Diagnoses Code(s)|Procedure Code(s)

*Instance #2* - The file was missing the last three columns and it failed as expected with the 'skipping data rows' message.

**Expected Header**
Address|Address2|City|State|ZIP|County|ServiceArea_Ind|Phone|Telehealth_Ind|IHS_THS_Ind|Partcipating_Ind|BHDP_Tier|BHDP_CLSS_Elig|BHDP_COD_Elig

**Actual Header**
Address|Address2|City|State|ZIP|County|ServiceArea_Ind|Phone|Telehealth_Ind|IHS_THS_Ind|Partcipating_Ind

*Instance #3* - There was an extra pipe delimiter between the last column and the 2nd to the last column. There was no error and it loaded the extra pipe into the cell with the data. So instead of 'NM' ,it was '|NM'.

**Expected Header**
SoloProv_Ind|GrpNPI|GrpName|TIN|DMAP_ID|CredDate|Address|Address2|City|State|ZIP|County|ServiceArea_Ind|Phone|Accept_Ind|BHDP_Tier|BHDP_CLSS_Elig|BHDP_COD_Elig

**Actual Header**
SoloProv_Ind|GrpNPI|GrpName|TIN|DMAP_ID|CredDate|Address|Address2|City|State|ZIP|County|ServiceArea_Ind|Phone|Accept_Ind|BHDP_Tier|BHDP_CLSS_Elig||BHDP_COD_Elig

Thie is causing issues with incorrect data being loaded. Why does it not always give and error? Is there a setting that makes ssis be more forgiving with the headers?

Comment: In the 3 instances of data files do the number of columns in the rows match the number of columns in the header, so if a file is missing three columns in the header all data rows in the file are also missing the same 3 columns? Also in #instance 2 example I think the expected and actual should be the other way round?

Comment: @PaolodeSinno - That is correct for instances 1 and 2. The columns matched the number of headers. In instance 3 the extra delimiter created a blank column between BHDP_CLSS_Elig and BHDP_COD_Elig. In instance 3, if the value was 'N' then it loaded fine. If is was 'NM' then it loaded the delimiter as a character '|NM' into the table. And thanks for catching my error in instance 2. It has been corrected.